# Size class initially unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, size-classes

I am trying to setup my UI on my universal app. I have a storyboard setup with size classes, a fairly simple UI. I have my view controller with a view in. Inside this view, I draw a chart so this can only be updated using `setFrame`.

This is where my problem begins. I set my graph to be the screen width. However, when the view initially runs, the size class seems to be unknown.

As the default 'Any' size in my storyboard is 600x600. My view thinks it should draw 600 wide on my iPhone, which clearly isn't this wide.

It is only after I physically move the iPhone to toggle an orientation change, that it updates and recognises the correct size.

So my question is, how do I prevent this problem? I need my UI to know what size to be from the get go, not just after the user rotates their iPhone.

Comment: Where are you setting the frame size? You need to do this in `viewWillAppear` or later once layout has happened. If you do it within `viewDidLoad` the frame size may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two to prevent this problem

(1) Load your entire method in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
}
```

(2) Do the following step

- Go to file Inspector
- Uncheck "Use size classed

Comment: I would take your first suggestion. However, I am initially a lot in the subview, UIView, not the view controller. Best just use a delegate to tell it when to update? Or is there a good UIView solution.

Comment: Try this method for update your all UIview frame -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{ set your UIview frame } @JoshKahane

Comment: Success. I had to update things a bit, so only frame updates occur here. Otherwise my whole UI multiplies and freaks out. But this seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Have done, don't worry! Appreciate the support. Credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 2):

> However, when the view initially runs, the size class seems to be unknown.

It is unknown to the view and the view controller, because at that time the view controller is not yet part of the interface and has no environment. But it is not unknown to `UIScreen.mainScreen()`. So if you need this information very early, that is who to ask.

However, as you've been advised in a comment, it also sounds like you may simply be doing this *too* early. Nothing in a view controller's view, including the view itself, has achieved its actual size until `viewDidLoad` or later.